# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module “pantheon-filechooser-module”

Tags: linux

I am a green hand on Linux and am now on Elementary OS Loki.
I met a problem when I tried to access to Software Sources with the command line:

```
gksudo software-properties-gtk
```

This is what I received:

```
> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
> (gksudo:21308): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in
> module_path: "pixmap", (gksudo:21308): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to
> locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", (gksudo:21308):
> Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path:
> "pixmap", (gksudo:21308): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme
> engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

Just to be more specific, this problem happened after I made an `autoremove`. I think probably I have wrongly deleted some package useful.

All answers will be appricated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below command resolve pixmap dependence.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

You can to see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1525664) response from Daniel Foré, (AKA Elementary´s creator) about filechooser bug.